# How to do you copy letters from a file and put them into a string to compare without using stdio

Tags: c, substring, system-calls

I'm trying to do a substring search using sys calls. I'm trying to use put the letters from a file into a string and then use string compare to check if they match.

```
for(int num = 2; num < argc; num++)
    {
      int fp = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
      int sizeofbar = strlen(argv[1]);
      char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeofbar+1);
      int count = 0;  //counter for output                                      
      int cur = 0;
      char* string2 = argv[num];
      int sizeofcompare = strlen(string2);

      read(fp, buf, sizeofcompare);

      for (cur = 0; cur < sizeofbar; cur++)
        {

    }

      write(STDOUT_FILENO, &count, sizeof(count));
      close(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot `write` to a string (`char *`). Get the file size, allocate buffer for its contents, `read` there. Then compare buffers (after ensuring that they look like strings\0).

Comment: Hit a C textbook or tutorial, specifically the file I/O chapter. Get that straightened out, then worry about the substring.

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652274/why-wont-the-program-read-from-the-2-argument-file/21652602#21652602

Comment: So I get that I should compare the letters with the buffer but how to I compare a small part of the buffer?

Comment: `strncmp`, `memcmp` and/or `bcmp` may be useful.